# How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd, permissions, mount

I am using a Sony Xperia M4 Aqua. As is well known, the internal memory is rather small. Especially the `Media` directory of `WhatsApp` uses a lot of precious space, therefore I am trying to move it to the SD card.
I am using Android 6 and I have formatted the SD card to have an adopted storage partition.

Adopted storage would be normally used to migrate all `/data` to it, as discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214233/304476).
I am however interested in moving just the single directory `WhatsApp/Media` somewhere else (possibly in the adopted storage partition), and then bind-mount it to its original location.

For this purpose, I moved the `WhatsApp/Media` directory to the adopted storage. Then, following [this discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/how-can-i-make-a-symlink-or-equivalent-inside-storage-emulated-0), I have modified the script `/system/etc/init.qcom.post_boot.sh` adding the following `mount`commands (the phone has no support for `init.d` scripts)

```
mount -o bind /mnt/expand/4fdb2500-9aa7-44bc-a2c4-80aeae28e764/WhatsAppMedia /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
mount -o bind /mnt/expand/4fdb2500-9aa7-44bc-a2c4-80aeae28e764/WhatsAppMedia /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
mount -o bind /mnt/expand/4fdb2500-9aa7-44bc-a2c4-80aeae28e764/WhatsAppMedia /mnt/runtime/read/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
mount -o bind /mnt/expand/4fdb2500-9aa7-44bc-a2c4-80aeae28e764/WhatsAppMedia /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
mount -o bind /mnt/expand/4fdb2500-9aa7-44bc-a2c4-80aeae28e764/WhatsAppMedia /data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media
```

Notice: `/mnt/expand/4fdb25....` points to the adopted storage partition.

This only apparently works: if I open a shell with `adb` I can correctly see that the `WhatsApp/Media` directory contains the mounted directory. Also, I see no additional views that contains the WhatsApp directory, as can be checked by doing, in an `adb shell`

```
find / -type d -name WhatsApp
```

Nevertheless, WhatsApp is not able to access the Media gallery. For instance, in the chat I just see blurred pictures (like a preview), and clicking on it I do not see the full picture. Moreover, if somebody sends me a picture, all I can see is a blurred preview with the download icon. Clicking on the download icon does not produce anything.

Wrong permissions are presumably the source of problems. For example, some permissions/group ownership appear to be incorrect on some views:

```
root@E2303:/ # ls -n /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 14:37 Backups
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-10-19 02:00 Databases
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 20:24 Media
root@E2303:/ # ls -n /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
drwxrwx--- 0        9997              2019-09-04 14:37 Backups
drwxrwx--- 0        9997              2019-10-19 02:00 Databases
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 20:24 Media
root@E2303:/ # ls -n /mnt/runtime/read/emulated/0/WhatsApp
drwxr-x--- 0        9997              2019-09-04 14:37 Backups
drwxr-x--- 0        9997              2019-10-19 02:00 Databases
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 20:24 Media
root@E2303:/ # ls -n /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/WhatsApp
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 14:37 Backups
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-10-19 02:00 Databases
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 20:24 Media
root@E2303:/ # ls -n /data/media/0/WhatsApp/                                   
drwxrwxr-x 1023     1023              2019-09-04 14:37 Backups
drwxrwxr-x 1023     1023              2019-10-19 02:00 Databases
drwxrwx--x 0        1015              2019-09-04 20:24 Media
```

Permissions and group ownership of the `Media` directory should be the same of the other (non bind-mounted) directories `Backups` and `Databases`.
Oddly enough, an attempt to remount the directories with the correct gid

```
root@E2303:/ # mount -o remount, gid=9997 /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
root@E2303:/ # mount -o remount, gid=9997 /mnt/runtime/read/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media
root@E2303:/ # mount -o remount, gid=1023 /data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media
```

does not produce any changes in the group ownership: `ls -n` as above gives identical results.

Even more strange, but maybe unrelated, omitting the space between `remount` and `gid=...` results in

```
mount: Invalid argument
```

How to bind mount `WhatsApp/Media` folder from external SD card with correct permissions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have been using two different approaches (in fact many with small differences) on my older Android versions to mount whole `/sdcard/WhatsApp` directory from external SD card. I have tested, it works on Android 9 too, but the storage things have changed on Android 10.

Before getting into practical details, we need to keep in mind a few points:

- `/sdcard` isn't an actual but **emulated filesystem**. Android uses `sdcardfs` (or `FUSE`) to emulate actual storage on `/sdcard`. See [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)
- Both of the above filesystems have a **fixed SELinux context**: `u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0` (or `u:object_r:fuse:s0`).
- Normally **`/data/media`** is emulated over `/sdcard`, but in case of Adoptable Storage when data is migrated, **`/mnt/expand/[UUID]/media`** is emulated. See [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)
- Files and directories on `/sdcard` have **fixed ownership and permissions** which depend on if the app has `android.permission.[READ|WRITE]_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission granted or not. Files have never executable permission. Apps' data directories in `/sdcard/Android/data/` have ownership set to respective app's UID. For details see [What is the “u#_everybody” UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526)

  We assume here that every app is allowed to write to `/sdcard` by setting ownership `0`/`9997` (user/group) and permissions `0771`/`0660` (directories/files).
- To achieve above said behavior, since Android 6 every app is run in an **isolated mount namespace** and `/storage/emulated` is bind mounted to a different *VIEW*: `/mnt/runtime/[default|read|write]/emulated` with private/slave mount propagation. So mounting directly to `/storage/emulated` won't appear in apps' mount namespaces unless you enter every app's mount namespace explicitly. The same is true if you mount from some app's isolated mount namespace. See [Partition gets unmounted automatically in Android Oreo](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526).

  We are going to mount from root mount namespace to `/mnt/runtime/write/emulated` which is propagated to all apps' mount namespaces.
- `read` and `default` views have different permissions than `write` <sup>([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526))</sup>, but mounting to both is usually unnecessary. Permissions `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` belong to same permission group. So granting one to an app through GUI also grants the other, and all apps with Storage permission will only see `write` view. `default` is only to let apps (which don't have READ/WRITE Storage permission) traverse `/sdcard/Android/data` directories. So mounting to `default` will let such apps just pass through subdirectories on `/sdcard/`, no files will be visible.

  Also at least with `sdcardfs` emulation, `read` and `write` are bind-mounted <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/sdcard/sdcard.cpp#128))</sup> from `default` and mounting to one also mounts to other two. So it's not possible to mount all of three with different permissions.
- `/sdcard` does not support Extended Attributes (`xattr`) and Access Time (`atime`). Other mount options include `nosuid`, `nodev` and `noexec`. See [mount manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) for details.

---

First of all make sure you are in root mount namespace as explained in the link given above. Or use `nsenter` to get a root shell in global namespace:

```
~# [ $(readlink /proc/1/ns/mnt) = $(readlink /proc/self/ns/mnt) ] || busybox nsenter -t 1 -m /system/bin/sh
```

### 1. MOUNT SD CARD MANUALLY:

The straightforward way is to format external SD card as portable storage with `exFAT` or `FAT32`. Since these filesystems aren't native to Linux, their in-kernel driver implementations support `uid`, `gid`, `fmask` and `dmask` mount options. You can use `exfat` or `sdfat` drivers with `exFAT` and `vfat` with `FAT32`. Former has also a userspace implementation [`mount.exfat-fuse`](https://github.com/relan/exfat) which requires only FUSE support from kernel. Check with `grep fuse /proc/filesystems`.

Let's say `/dev/block/sda1` is your `exFAT` partition:

```
~# mount -t exfat -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,context=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0,uid=0,gid=9997,fmask=0117,dmask=0006 /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
~# mv /data/media/0/WhatsApp/* /sdcard/WhatsApp/
```

<sup>* Replace `u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0` with `u:object_r:fuse:s0` or whatever label your `/sdcard` has.</sup>

You can also create multiple partitions on SD card. Or after mounting with required mount options you may also bind mount a directory instead of whole partition. Let's say you first mount SD card to `/mnt/my_sdcard`, then bind mount WhatsApp directory:

```
~# mount -o bind /mnt/my_sdcard/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
```

**Downside** with this approach is that `vold` mounts external SD card on boot, so you need to un-mount first.
Secondly the data on SD card isn't encrypted, though there are multiple ways to encrypt manually. See [Decrypting microSD card on another Android device or desktop computer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216780/218526).

### 2. ADOPTABLE STORAGE:

An easy way to counter the above said downsides is to make use of kernel's built-in FDE by formatting the SD card as Adoptable Storage, but only if you don't want to [migrate](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526) all `/data/media/` to external SD card. Once formatted, external SD card will be mounted at `/mnt/expand/[UUID]` (filesystem [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Uses) is a 16 bytes number). But we can't simply bind mount a directory from there to `/sdcard` because the filesystem on Adoptable Storage is `ext4`, which follows UNIX permissions model but the apps can't handle those as explained above. Even if you make it work somehow (using `chown`, `chmod` etc.), every app will create files with its own UID which won't be accessible to other apps e.g. Gallery may not be able see pictures downloaded by WhatsApp.

For this method to work your kernel must support `sdcardfs` (check with `grep sdcardfs /proc/filesystems`). Create a directory on Adopted SD card and emulate it to `/sdcard/WhatsApp`:

```
~# mkdir /mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0/WhatsApp
~# mv /sdcard/WhatsApp/* /mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0/WhatsApp/
~# restorecon -rv /mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/
~# mount -t sdcardfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mask=7,gid=9997 /mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Whatsapp
```

Please note that we necessarily need to use path `/mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/` because it's labeled as `media_rw_data_file` <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/private/file_contexts#471))</sup> (like `/data/media` <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/private/file_contexts#384))</sup>) which is allowed by SELinux policy to be accessed by apps <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/private/isolated_app.te#30))</sup>. If you use a different path, you need to modify SELinux policy. Unlike other filesystems `sdcardfs` itself doesn't change SELinux context when accessing underlying filesystem.

### 3. PORTABLE / ADOPTABLE STORAGE:

This method is the most flexible, it works if you want to use:

- Portable storage but don't want to mount whole partition, instead a directory.
- Adoptable storage but your kernel doesn't have `sdcardfs` support.
- Adoptable storage but don't want to use `/mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/` path necessarily.

Use a third party tool named [`bindfs`](https://bindfs.org/) (which uses FUSE) to simulate the behavior of emulated filesystem. Actually Android's built-in tool `/system/bin/sdcard` does exactly this on [pre-`sdcardfs` releases](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/68e1093028185cde31dcacf34a59f6c08848d3d4) but it has some fixed paths and other unnecessary things, so its source code needs to be modified to achieve what we want. You can build `bindfs` yourself or try <strike>[this](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261604574)</strike> [this](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261681311) one.

```
~# DIR=/mnt/media_rw/[UUID]    # for Portable Storage
~# DIR=/mnt/expand/[UUID]      # for Adoptable Storage
~# mkdir $DIR/WhatsApp
~# mv /sdcard/WhatsApp/* $DIR/WhatsApp/
~# bindfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,context=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 -u 0 -g 9997 -p a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --create-with-perms=a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --xattr-none --chown-ignore --chgrp-ignore --chmod-ignore $DIR/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
```

***Side notes:***

- `sdcardfs` also works partially with this method except it doesn't support SELinux `context=` option (so far). So it depends on what is the SELinux label of backing directory on SD card.
- Other tools like `rclone`, `encfs`, `sshfs` etc. which make use of FUSE can also be mounted inside `/sdcard` the same way. Related: [How to mount rclone on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/218526)
- `-u` and `-g` options require `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to exist on `bindfs` < v[1.14.2](https://github.com/mpartel/bindfs/issues/79).

---

So you may go with whatever method suits you. Usually in-kernel drivers perform better than userspace solutions, and methods native to Linux kernel are more robust and stable. FUSE (over FUSE) may exert performance penalty sometimes e.g. if SD card itself supports high speed data transfers.

You can place the required mount commands in an `init.d` script or define and `init` service. See [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

**Note:**

- Apps which don't scan `/sdcard` filesystem themselves but rely on Android's MediaProvider for any changes may need a [forced media scan](https://github.com/zhuowei/scanmediaplz) for new files on mounted filesystem to appear immediately.
- If you use multiple users or profiles, you need to mount new filesystem for every `User_ID`. For device owner it's `0`.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to bind-mount “data” and “obb” folders from external SD card in “/sdcard/Android”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219514/218526)

Comment: Hi Irfan . Going through your meticulous answer... ( and thanks for the same ) ... My situation is a multi `partitioned ext4 `  card where even the main partition is `ext4`. My ROM is a Stock ROM  that will unlike `lineage` not support `ext4 mount` out of box . I can `mount` my `partitions` with an approach similar to `init.d` and they are visible to `rooted TC` apps but they are not RW. I would like `partition` wide `RW` for  certain apps. Not just private dirs. I tried `vold-posix` it does not like my OS and arch. n`ot executable: 64-bit ELF file` I get this error for `bindfs`. Any other ?

Comment: `getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist gives  armeabi-v7a,armeabi` . Any other approach so I can get a `RW partition` wide `mount` for  specific `rooted `and non rooted apps ( non rooted app is stock ROM's file manager that is invoked by default by all apps to traverse directories ) . As I understand ,Android 'deprecates this but I'd  appreciate it' , if you can throw in your 2 cents !

Comment: If this `partition wide` approach is not feasible then at the time of mounting  want to give specific app IDs RW.  as part of mount. How can I do this ?

Comment: @user1874594 we have been through similar discussions on your previous questions and could hardly conclude anything. So I don't think I'd be able to explain anything newer than what I've already done. I don't have a 32-bit ARM `bindfs` binary, you have to build from source. If you can't, let me know and I'll build one for you when I get time. As far as your other queries are concerned, they cannot be explained (again) in comments. You may ask a precise and unique question with all necessary information and I can try to briefly explain steps specific to your situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60770589/1874594

Comment: yes this has been discussed in different context after that I could manage mounting part but making it RW is where I am stuck and I hope I am clear now sorry I do apologize if I wasn't clear enough articulating my situation and objective

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222205/making-manually-mounted-partition-folders-write-accessible-to-all-apps                                                                                sorry I moved it to Android Stack from 'regular stack' above is the right link

Comment: @IrfanLatif Great answer. It works as expected, but it doesn't seem I'm able to unmount a mount I make this way. The original `mount` command creates the three mounts in `/mnt/runtime` along with two duplicate mounts in `/storage/emulated/0`. `umount` called on these directories returns no errors, but trying to re-mount to the same directory later doesn't propagate to non-root namespaces. SELinux is set to permissive. Only thing that fixes it is a reboot of the tablet. Using LineageOS 16.0 (Android 9) with Magisk.

Comment: This is for an in-car tablet with OTG storage via permanently-mounted USB hub. When powered-off and back on, the OTG storage needs to be unmounted and then remounted, since the device gets re-probed (i.e. `/dev/block/sdb1` will disappear on loss of power, and then when power is applied, it will appear again as `/dev/block/sdc1`).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I made a question here... I'd greatly appreciate any input you can provide: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230436/how-to-properly-propagate-unmounting-of-usb-otg-storage-to-all-mount-namespaces

Comment: @IrfanLatif How do you build the bindfs?

Comment: @Jtnqr using [GCC](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I compiled `bindfs  ` and it does seem to atleast execute with whatever options you have shown. I am on Android 10. Unfortunately after trying each and every option with various ` user id and group ID's ` and ` mounting ` options..... I am still not able to get right access to the target folder which is actually the ` WhatsApp ` folder. in light of this can you please modify your  answer for Android 10 or else maybe del it ✌️

Comment: @IrfanLatif :  just to update. With  `bindfs`  I can  as much as re-name with `non root`  privs. But creating  folders is a NO.  Any combination  .Here is my context for the target `u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 ` so why is that no Folders cant be created .  I see something like an untrusted process app is accessing media_rw . But that 's happening with your `bindfs` e.g.  as well. Any ts-shooting help wd be appreciated ✌️