# mounting an app folder to external storage fails for Write access on Android Q but will work in Android Pie

Tags: storage, permissions, mount, partitions, bind-mount

I could mount my partitions holding whatsapp (exFat) and titanium  ( ext4 ) backup data on `android Pie`  but right now on `Q`  it will not let a RW operation be performed after mounting 
I understand /sdcard is a virtual emulated FS and the fact that there are app specific views etc. But after going through all that perplexing stuff, I couldn't crystallize on a working solution. 
I've gone through a [related Q](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions/217936#217936) on stack but none of these approaches work for me.
So lemme explain a bit where I come from
 :

{} I can successfully `bind mount /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp` to `exFat /storage/[UUID]/WhatsApp` for `RW`. Obviously because `exFat` is `Permission` unaware file system. Did a regular mount and it will mount to `/mnt/media/runtime/[Read & Write & Full &  Default]` with 3 separate `'mask'` options `mask==6 , 7 and 23` ( BTW that mask option isn't quite your `umask` . Its '*decimalized*' `umask` -convert that 7 to binary to get real `umask` ). So in fact it invokes the same path as mentioned in the article behind the covers viz  `/mnt/media/runtime/[Read & Write & Full &  Default]`

{} I need to similarly mount  an `ext4` `partition` with `Titanium backup`. Here are the issues.
If I mount  /storage/emulated/0/Titanium to `ext4 /storage/[UUID]/Titanium`  ( like I mentioned in fact it mounts to `/mnt/media/runtime/[Read & Write & Full &  Default]` with 3 separate `'mask'` options  underneath. With this mount. I can  Restore Apps but cant backup Apps. So R is allowed `RW` is not and I granted Titanium Root access. Maybe the explorer components of that apps are not using Root level access. 
Somewhere i read - mount using correct options of `sdcardfs` and 'fuse`. My question is *precisely How* ?

{} I found somewhere a `bindfs binary` but it does not work with my  `CPU Architecture`

{} Now with everything the same I Could `RW` using above approach in `Android Pie` . This is an issue with `Android Q` ...what changed ? how do I work around ?