# How to mount rclone on Android?

Tags: mount, google-drive, magisk

I had `rclone` mount my Google Drive on my Android 7 box with the [Magisk module](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/com.piyushgarg.rclone) and Termux. But it has stopped working and now there's only an empty folder. This is the `rclone` log:

```
2020/06/03 07:33:54 mount helper error: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "fusermount": library "libandroid-support.so" not found
2020/06/03 07:33:54 Fatal error: failed to mount FUSE fs: fusermount: signal: aborted.
```

I just want to mount `rclone` on my rooted HiMedia Q10 Pro Android TV box so that I can view my GDrive as a permanent folder on my file system.

Answer (score 9):

The Magisk module you linked is using `fusermount` binary from [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/fusermount-android-rclone-mount-t3866652) which is built for Termux environment. But `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is not being set properly in the module, so the error occurs. A simple approach is to use static `fusermount` binary, I already posted in the [same thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80237591&postcount=34).

`rclone` uses FUSE which you can mount manually from CLI without relying on Magisk module. I have explained in detail [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526). Some issues related to using FUSE on Android are explained in [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75721227&postcount=9). Here I'm describing steps briefly related to `rclone` only. I'm using Termux for explanation. You can use some other terminal emulator app or `adb shell` with differences in paths.

Instructions below require that **you have a rooted device**.

- Install `rclone` binary available in Termux repos (by running `pkg install rclone`) or download from <strike>[official website](https://rclone.org/downloads/)</strike> [official website](https://beta.rclone.org/test/testbuilds-latest/). Download static `fusermount` binary from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=76462538&postcount=68) (available for both `aarch64` and `armeabi-v7a`). Extract the downloaded archive files. I assume that downloaded files are placed in `/sdcard/Download/`.
- For ease of repeated use create a shell script `/sdcard/Download/rclone_mount.sh` using any text editor. Copy/paste the following lines:

  ```
  #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash -e

  # must be run with root privileges
  [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] || exec su --mount-master -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH HOME=$HOME PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin $0"

  # make sure to be in root mount namespace
  [ $(readlink /proc/1/ns/mnt) = $(readlink /proc/self/ns/mnt) ] || nsenter -t 1 -m -- "$0"

  Unmount() {
      fusermount -u /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/GDrive 2>/dev/null || :
  }

  # make sure it's not already mounted
  Unmount

  # make sure it's unmounted after rclone is killed
  trap 'sleep 1; Unmount' EXIT

  # mount remote in /sdcard/
  rclone -v mount GDrive: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/GDrive --gid 9997 --dir-perms 0771 --file-perms 0660 --umask=0 --allow-other
  ```

  See [`rclone mount` manual](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) for explanation on commandline options. Some options may impact the performance.
- Make sure Termux is granted Storage permission and execute following commands:

  ```
  ~$ cd
  ~$ pkg install -y util-linux
  ~$ mkdir -p bin /sdcard/GDrive
  ~$ cp /sdcard/Download/{fusermount,rclone,rclone_mount.sh} bin/
  ~$ chmod -R 0755 bin
  ~$ dos2unix bin/rclone_mount.sh
  ~$ bin/rclone config
  ```

  Follow the instruction on screen (see [`rclone config` manual](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_config/) for details) to create configuration file (`~/.config/rclone/rclone.conf`) for Google Drive (or whatever remote service you want to use). I assume you chose the remote name `GDrive` (as used in above script).

---

Whenever you need to mount `rclone`, open Termux and run `bin/rclone_mount.sh` (or create [Termux Widget](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Widget) to run the script from home screen conveniently).

- All apps with Storage permissions should be able to explore `GDrive` folder (bind mounting to `read` and `default` views isn't necessarily required). But some apps may crash due to slow network activity, others may require more caching (see options) etc.
- Trigger a [Media Scan](https://github.com/zhuowei/scanmediaplz) if e.g. pictures on remote don't appear in gallery app.
- When done press `Ctrl ^C` to stop `rclone` process and mount.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. You answered about 16 months ago. Is it still the case that the fusermount binary needs to be changed? I'm using rclone-mount 1.16 Magisk module which comes from https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/com.piyushgarg.rclone. I'm not using Termux and I would prefer a fully automatic full-time mount (which I assume the Magisk module provides). `My question is, after 16 months, do you still recommend the Termux approach as described in your answer instead of Magisk module?`

Comment: @MountainX I don't use Magisk module, so can't say how well it works. But the manual method I explained should always work. This is how it'll work on any UNIX-like operating system including Android.

Comment: So... I have the Magisk module installed. I did a good bit of troubleshooting & it still is not working. Now I tried running your mount command `rclone -v mount MYMOUNT: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/MYMOUNT --gid 9997 --dir-perms 0771 --file-perms 0660 --umask=0 --allow-other` and it works as expected. I did not change my binaries or use Termux or run your script. I just ran the mount cmd as root. Curious why the the Magisk module mounts are failing when clearly my config and my binaries are capable of working. But I do plan to use your approach. I like that it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a related question here: [scripts - How to use rclone-mount with Termux:Boot? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242247/how-to-use-rclone-mount-with-termuxboot "scripts - How to use rclone-mount with Termux:Boot? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange"). I'm not having success with Termux:Boot yet.

Comment: I posted two more related questions:  

[Termux: bad interpreter: Permission denied](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242265/)
  and 
[permission denied only AFTER becoming root in Termux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242292/)

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this: [How to automate rclone-mount without Termux or Magisk? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242370/how-to-automate-rclone-mount-without-termux-or-magisk/242371#242371 "How to automate rclone-mount without Termux or Magisk? - Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange")

Comment: @IrfanLatif I believe this approach is no longer need in Android 12. I have managed to mount rclone with a simple command but the problem is that there is no write access, only read and the /mnt/runtime directory seems always empty on Android 12? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The directory tree seems to end here: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated

Comment: I used this method for years to mount pCloud on my phone. But recently I moved to a new model. I tried to setup the mount in the same way, but I got the following error when calling to rclone_mount.sh: `2024/02/16 09:35:38 ERROR : /: Dir.Stat error: couldn't list files: Get "https://eapi.pcloud.com/listfolder?folderid=0": dial tcp: lookup eapi.pcloud.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:41532->[::1]:53: read: connection refused`

The directory to which the cloud storage should be mounted was empty.

Comment: If anyone interested, here is how I solved it. First, I updated rclone binary to a newer version. Most likely pCloud's API has changed and the old binary didn't handle it properly. Second, I replaced this `nsenter -t 1 -m -- "$0"` with `nsenter -t 1 -m -- "$HOME/bin/rclone_mount.sh`. Lastly, I created a link to `fusermount`, so it would also be recognized as `fusermount3`: `ln -s $HOME/bin/fusermount $HOME/bin/fusermount3`. Now everything works properly.