# How to easily access and browse 100GB of photos of the local network's NAS?

Tags: storage, networking, photos, cloud

I don't use Google Photos, iCloud photos or any other (distant) cloud photos storage service.

All my 100 GB photos are stored on a hard drive connected on a NAS of my home router (of course, I have backup on other disks distant from home, etc. but that's another off-topic question...).

**From my Android phone, how to easily browse the photos of my local network's NAS?** With thumbnails, etc. like most photo browsers.

---

NB: my NAS is a DIY-NAS made with a Raspberry Pi, with a SMB Samba server, but I can easily install another server on this Raspberry Pi if needed.

Comment: Mount SMB if your device is rooted. Otherwise use some file explorer with SMB implementation. Try `rclone` on both sides if you want something very simple: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/218526. Mount NFS if you want something complicated: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201191/218526. May also try SSHFS.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I'm not rooted. I have tried an Explorer with SMB implementation, it works. But it's probably not the best to browse thousands of images, to be able to "swipe right" to go to the next image, to see thumbnails, etc. Do you have any idea about an app that would be nice for that?