# Termux: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: root-access, termux

I'm attempting to execute this command in a Termux:Boot script.

```
 exec su --mount-master -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH HOME=$HOME PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin $0"
```

I get this error:

```
: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/su: \
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

However, I can execute the command directly (without the `exec`) on the command line without any errors and I get the root prompt as expected.

The command comes from https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/12444

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash -e

[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] || exec su --mount-master -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH HOME=$HOME PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin $0"
```

Also, as part of trying to get that entire script to work on my device, I am trying this in Termux:

```
$ tsu
# rclone -v mount GDrive: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/GDrive --gid 9997 --dir-perms 0771 --file-perms 0660 --umask=0 --allow-other
```

This gives the error:

```
# bash: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rclone: Permission denied
```

The permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u0_a212 u0_a212 62257128 Oct 21 16:57 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rclone
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/MrBIMC/SELinuxModeChanger

Comment: @alecxs luckily, my SELinux mode is already permissive, but that's a good link anyway. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: try Termux:Boot with this script and check *'/sdcard/termux.log'* for debugging purposes https://pastebin.com/vqeWK60E

Comment: @alecxs: good idea. Thanks. Will run that and report back. Also, I have made some progress, so I will update the question. I also need to post a new question related to https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/scripts/emulator.sh

Comment: @alecxs - I updated our chat room with results. Need your suggestions on next step.