# How to access sync'd Nextcloud files in termux

Tags: root-access, termux

I am syncing files to my phone (Fairphone 4) with Nextcloud, and wish to access these files using termux. Currently access is denied, is there a way to set this up to work other than rooting the device or is that the way forward?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Termux cannot pass SAF-based storage access (like you would do with a file explorer by selecting - for example - a file using Google Drive app).

But there is an alternative : Rclone.
Rclone can give you access to many and many online drives (including NextCloud). It is only a command-line utility.

To install it in Termux, simply run `pkg in rclone`.
Then, you need to set the remotes (= online drives) you want : `rclone config`. See the [docs](https://rclone.org/docs/) to know how to add remotes correctly.

Say you now have a remote with the name "myRemote", you can do whatever you want :

- Copy a file to current local directory in Termux : `rclone copy myRemote:file2Copy.txt .`
- List the files on the remote : `rclone ls myRemote:`
- Etc...

The only drawback, is that you can only access to rclone remotes using a terminal.

There is a way to mount rclone remotes on the device, but you need to be rooted. Check this great [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/370078) if you are interested.