# How to mount network drive so it's accessible by other apps file picker?

Tags: file-system, cifs

I have a handful of apps that have file pickers, but they only show me what is in `/storage/emulated/0` (also shown on my phone as "Internal Storage") and below. I want to mount a NAS so that i can access the files through these other apps but I can't figure out how.

Mounting the network drive with Cx File Explorer or SolidExplorer does not seem to make the drive accessible to other apps.

Is there a way to mount the NAS as a subdirectory of the internal storage? Or create a symbolic link to the mounted network drive?

EDIT: From searching more it seems that SolidExplorer/CxFileManager do not mount the network drive as a "system wide" drive. Nor does it seem that stock Pixel 6/6 Pro kernels support CIFS.

Not sure what to do as i'm not looking to flash a new kernel or rom.

Comment: [How to mount NFS / CIFS on Android with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201191/218526)

Comment: [How to mount rclone on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/218526)

Comment: [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)

Comment: None of the above is possible without root.

Comment: Apps that have no root access like Cx File Explorer can not mount anything or modify the system in a way that other apps would notice, that is prohibited by Android. So if such an app "mounts" a NAS drive it simply connects to it and allows you to browser the remote files and upload/download/delete files or folders.

Comment: As Irfan pointed out, providing a system-wide mount will most certainly require root permissions. You can find some helpful candidates here then: My app-listing [Mount Remote Drives](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_mount) has the few (currently only 5) apps known for this purpose (if an unknown candidate exists, I'll gladly add it).