# How to properly propagate unmounting of USB OTG storage to all mount namespaces (rooted device)

Tags: mount, usb-on-the-go, file-permissions

This is a (spiritual) follow-up to the previously answered question [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions/217936#217936).

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 8.0 
ROM: LineageOS 16.0 (Android 9) with Magisk 
Other things to note: SELinux set to permissive

This in-car tablet with OTG storage via permanently-mounted USB hub. When the car is powered on, the tablet, USB hub, and any peripherals receive power, the tablet switches into OTG mode, and all USB devices are enumerated correctly (confirmed via `lsusb` in a root shell).

If I reboot the tablet while it is powered, then use the instructions in the above-linked answer, everything seems to work as intended. In summary, after booting, I can mount my USB device to its mount-point as follows

```
$ su -mm (switch to a global namespace root shell)
# mkdir /data/media/0/usb1 (create the mount point)
# mount -t exfat -o <options string> /dev/block/sdb1 /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/usb1
```

which results in the following mounts:

```
# mount
...
/dev/block/sdb1 on /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/usb1 <options>
/dev/block/sdb1 on /mnt/runtime/read/emulated/0/usb1 <options>
/dev/block/sdb1 on /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/usb1 <options>
/dev/block/sdb1 on /storage/emulated/0/usb1 <options>
/dev/block/sdb1 on /storage/emulated/0/usb1 <options>
```

Just to be clear, the final mount to `/storage/emulated/0/usb1` does in fact appear twice. In any case, at this point, everything work as expected as long as the tablet remains powered; all apps can access the data on the USB OTG storage with no issue.

When powered-off and back on, the OTG storage needs to be unmounted and then remounted, since the device gets re-probed (e.g. the USB-OTG storage partition `/dev/block/sdb1` will disappear on loss of power, and then when power is applied, it will appear again as `/dev/block/sdc1`). I've narrowed the issue down to the fact that running `umount` in a global namespace root shell doesn't seem to propagate to all other mount namespaces. In a root shell, everything works just fine.

`umount` called on these mounts returns no errors and running `mount` in a root shell confirms that the drive is no longer mounted. However, even after this, it seems that all of the non-global mount namespaces still retain the mount. There are two things that indicate this:

1. It's impossible to delete the mount point directory, in any shell (including a root shell):

```
$ su -mm
# rmdir /data/media/0/usb1
rm: cannot remove /data/media/0/usb1 : Device or resource busy
```

I've tried running `lsof` in a root shell, but don't see anything holding a handle open to the mount point directory. I haven't built or downloaded an `nsenter` binary to switch into the mount namespace of different apps to check, but I suspect the mount is still held open in other namespaces. I say this because...

2. Apps can still access the USB-OTG storage, even after it's been unmounted in a root shell. The access remains until the tablet loses power, at which point the mount point directory appears empty to all applications. Upon power restoration, if I mount the new partition in `/dev/block` to the same mount point as before, root shells have no issue accessing the data, however all other apps just see it as an empty directory.

I've tried using a bind mount as follows...

```
# mount -t exfat /dev/block/sdb1 /mnt/media_rw/usb1
# mount -t sdcardfs /mnt/media_rw/usb1 /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/usb1
```

...but this just pushes the problem to the "base" mount point. On power loss and restore, remounting the exFAT mount and then the bind sdcardfs mount to /sdcard just results in an "empty" folder for apps, but the root shell works properly (both in the `/mnt/media_rw_usb1` directory as well as the mount point in `/sdcard/usb1`). In this case, it becomes impossible to delete the `/mnt/media_rw_usb1` directory with the same `Device or resource busy` error.

I'm thoroughly stumped on how to handle this. I've gotten by in the past by using a Tasker script to use `nsenter` to enter into the mount namespace of the apps I need to access the drive, and run loops to unmount the directory in question until an error returns, at which point I run a separate task to mount the OTG storage again. I'd like to avoid this approach, though, since it's really kludgy and it's actually quite slow.

I think I've given enough information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *while grep -qw '/[^ ]\*/usb1' /proc/mounts; do umount -l $(grep -owm1 '/[^ ]\*/usb1' /proc/mounts); done;* should unmount all old entries for */data/media/0/usb1* in a loop

Comment: @alecxs I'm not sure that will be of any use... the drive is actually unmounted in the shell. The issue is that the unmount is not propagating to all other app namespaces.

Comment: ah wait, you didn't meant the 5 lines in your question.. you can set namespaces to global in magisk settings

Comment: @alecxs That doesn't make any difference. Apps still run in their own mount namespaces on Android 6+

Comment: you must reboot to apply that settings

Comment: No... the global namespace setting in Magisk only applies to shells, not to running apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115458/discussion-between-shamtam-and-alecxs).

Comment: @IrfanLatif you may be the only person that understands what I'm asking

Comment: Mount propagation is complicated enough (but not impossible) to understand, and even more complicated to explain, at least in comments or an answer. Most probably you are dealing with a `slave` or `private` mount. So try with `mount --make-rslave` first. For how to use it, and why to use it, please see [mount](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) manpage.

Comment: Also read about the related concepts in [mount](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), [mount_namespaces](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) and [sharedsubtree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.rst). Keep `nsenter` and `unshare` binaries with you throughout your learning experience. I hope you find your answer and will be able to explain the concepts to others :)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I did a little more digging today and it seems the issue only appears as soon as I use the different runtime mounting views (i.e. mount anything to the `/mnt/runtime/{default,read,write}/...`. If I just mount to e.g. `/mnt/media_rw/usb1`, I can mount/unmount at will with no issues. Because of this, I suspect I'm running into an Android-specific issue where the kernel is holding a handle open to my mounted device. I will try your advice re: the subtree operations, however. Thanks!