# Is there any way to save data i.e. Screenshot/ photo to external storage by default

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage, screenshots

I am using Moto G. It is Android 6.0. Internal storage 16Gb.
Now I want to store all screenshot and photo/ video taken using default camera app and whatsapp/ other social media data to external storage.

What is problem:
As I came to know the option to select "save to external memory" or selecting external memory as default is removed from android 6 and above.

I know there is no short of internal memory but I want to keep/ preserve these data on external card even if I remove/ swap the external card. say for legal purposes.

Now the problem is if I format external SD card as portable it there is no option to select this as default storage. If I format external SD card as internal storage I can not remove it without loosing data.

So Is there any way to make apps to save all data to external storage by default.
I don't mind where apps are installed. Only I care about screenshots/ camera photo/ audio recording/ video recording/ whatsapp data etc.

Thank You all

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526

The Directory Binder option in Lucky Patcher might work as well. Haven't tried it out myself though, so no promises.