# How to change permissions for SD card directory under /storage

Tags: external-sd, permissions, file-permissions

I have symlinked /data/media/0/Download to /storage/15B3-16E4/Download so that files will save to my SD card, but apps can't write to it because the owner/permissions are wrong.

```
adb shell su -c ls -ld /data/media/0/Movies
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw media_rw 4096 2022-08-10 19:16 /data/media/0/Movies

adb shell su -c ls -ld /storage/15B3-16E4/Download
drwxrwx--- 3 root everybody 32768 2022-08-27 17:15 /storage/15B3-16E4/Download
```

These commands do nothing. So does chmod.

```
adb shell su -c chown media_rw:media_rw /storage/15B3-16E4/Download

adb shell su -c /system/xbin/busybox chown media_rw:media_rw /storage/15B3-16E4/Download
```

How do I correct the permissions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions)

Comment: No, you haven't symlinked anything to /storage/15B3-16E4