# How can I mount an SD card as internal storage on Motorola Moto G Play 2023?

Tags: internal-storage, mount, motorola-moto-g, adoptable-storage

I have a Motorola Moto G Play 2023 (maui), Android 12, rooted through Magisk. It only comes with 32GB of storage, so I bought an SD card to hold more apps. Unfortunately, Motorola has decided that the Android version that ships with my phone shouldn't be able to merge an SD card as internal storage. Is there any way to either

1. get around this, or
2. just mount the SD card as internal storage?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/set-sd-card-as-default-android-6743109

Comment: @ChanganAuto, why not flesh it out and make it an answer?

Comment: @ChanganAuto That does not solve my problem. As I stated in the post, Motorola has disabled the option to format an SD card as internal storage. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)